# $_COOKIE reads wrong value of cookie

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I'm developing multilingual web app. When a user set's a language it gets stored in cookie. PHP script reads cookie and load appropriate language file. When user changes language cookie value is changed and page reloaded. PHP script still reads old (wrong) cookie value. I've tried "empty cache and reload" option in chrome and tried manually deleting cookie but PHP script still reads old cookie value. When I read cookie with JavaScript in console it returns new (correct) value.

Here is PHP code snippet that doesn't work:

```
  if (isset($_COOKIE['language'])) {
    $language = $_COOKIE['language'];
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/language/$language.php";
  }
  else {
    $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
    setcookie("language", $lang, time()+31104000);
    header($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
    die();
  }
```

I've searched the web but didn't find any answer or something that point's me to the solution.

PS: I'm using the same code snippet on another web app on the same server and it works.

EDIT: JavaScript code to change the language

```
 function changeLanguage(lang) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (31536000000));
  var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = "language=" + lang + "; " + expires;
  location.reload();
}
```

EDIT 2:
In HTTP header's there are two cookie's named language so it seems that the problem is caused by the javascript code.

Comment: where is the code for the user changing the language?

Comment: `$_COOKIE` is filled with the cookies that a client provided in the request. What is the contents of the `Cookie` header in the request?

Comment: Aside from any errors causing this...I wouldn't recommend doing `"/language/$language.php"` because you are using untrusted input from the user directly to access a file and run it. It could be exploited to access other files using `..` etc.

Comment: How are you determining that your PHP script is not working correctly?

Comment: It seems that cookie header has 2 cookies named language... One with old and one with new value

Comment: do both cookies have the same domain \ path scopes ?

Comment: Yes. Both have the same domain \ path

Comment: `Cookie` header in the request does not have domain/path. Can you show a screenshot with that complete request?

Answer (score 1):

```
header($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

If this is intended to redirect you're missing the `"Location: "` prefix. You probably also want a URL rather than a local filesystem path.

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: Even then, I don't think something like `Location: /var/www/html` would make for a good redirect

Comment: Thank you. I've changed it, but the problem is still here.

Comment: @Agi38 I'd question the need to have a server-side redirect at all. Restructure your code to detect or set the language cookie, **then** load the required language file. No redirects required